# Plot the density function of a normal random variable knowing only the characteristic function in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, density-function, fourier-transform, characteristic-function

The characteristic function of a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and
standard deviation $\sigma$ is:

$$\begin{alignat*}{1}
\hat{\phi}(t) & =e^{i\mu t}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}t^{2}}\\
 & =\exp(i\mu t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}t^{2})
\end{alignat*}$$

What I want to do is to plot the PDF of the normal random variable knowing only the characteristic function outlined above $\hat\phi(t)$. Ideally the solution to this problem would be to apply the Inverse Fourier Transform on $\hat\phi(t)$ and then plot the result for different values of $x$. Applying the Inverse Transform leads me to solve this integral to get the PDF of $x$:

$$\begin{alignat*}{1}
f(x) & =\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{\phi}(t)\exp(-itx)dt\\
 & =\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(i\mu t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}t^{2})\exp(- itx)dt\\
 & =\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(i\mu t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}t^{2}- itx)dt
\end{alignat*}
$$

The problem is that I do not know how to do it in R. I could use the `integrate()` function, but how do I treat the imaginary unit $i$?

Comment: Can't you just read off the coefficients of $t$ and $t^2$ in the characteristic function in order to deduce the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$?

Answer (score 4):

Just read off the coefficients of $t$ and $t^2$ in the characteristic function in order to deduce the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.  If the characteristic function is not (or cannot be put) in the form $exp(a i t - b t^2)$, where $a$ is a real number and $b$ is a non-negative real number, then it is not the characteristic function of a Normal random variable. If it is of that form, then $\mu = a$ and $\sigma^2 = 2 b$. Now plot a Normal density with those parameters to your heart's content.

Your formula for the probability density function is incorrect. it should be
$$\begin{alignat*}{1}
f(x) & =\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{\phi}(t)\exp(-itx)dt\\\end{alignat*}$$which lo and behold, comes out correct.

Comment: Ward Whitt and colleagues have devised some very clever numerical algorithms in the past to bring transforms back to the probability domain. Not just for normal distributions (which would be rather silly like Mark Stone remarked), but for general distributions as well). References can be provided although I doubt if R-implementations exist.

Comment: Thank you for you answer Mark. Sorry for the error in the formula, I have updated the question. What do you mean with "*read off the coefficients of $t$ and $t^2$ in the characteristic function*"? Unfortunately I have been introduced to concepts like the Fourier Transform and the characteristic function without having the proper theoretical background to understand them (it's a long story...), and now I'm asked to do things which, apparently, I cannot do.

Comment: What is your starting point for this process? Do you have an explicit characteristic function?  If so, what does one look like? it should match the form I described. If not, what does it look like?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Yes, I have the explicit characteristic function of the normal distribution, which is the following: $$\hat{\phi}(t) = \exp(i\mu t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}t^{2})$$ And I need to plot the density function using the inverse Fourier transform: $$f(x)  =\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{\phi}(t)\exp(-itx)dt$$

Comment: And the inverse Fourier transform can be evaluated exactly with the result being the pdf of $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.. In order to plot it, I think you're going to want to have specific numerical values for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ If this doesn't suffice, then why do you "need" to do it in some particular way?  Is it for a course assignment?

Comment: Yeah, I have understood that the result of applying the inverse Fourier transform to $\hat{\phi}(t)$ will get me to $f(x)$. But I thought there was some kind of way to solve this integral $$\begin{alignat*}{1}
f(x) & =\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{\phi}(t)\exp(-itx)dt\\\end{alignat*}$$ in R for different values of $x$, in order to get the PDF of a normal random variable. I know it is quite stupid, and it is because we all know the PDF of a normal dist., but it is in fact a course "assignment". The values for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are not specified… so I think I can invent them.

Comment: Applying the fourier transform Is pretty much the same idea either direction. You ought to get the idea how to do things looking at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformGaussian.html or the first couple of pages of http://web.mit.edu/8.03-esg/watkins/8.03/ft.pdf .Whether you're supposed to  symbolically or numerically evaluate the integrals, I leave to you. Or use an approach like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029956/calculating-a-density-from-the-characteristic-function-using-fft-in-r (I haven't checked the correctness myself). I don't know the expectations of your assignment.